# How to refresh Athena Views?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a table in Athena. New data gets added to S3 and this gives updated results when i run the Select statement. I have created a view on this select statement . But problem is the view does not give the updated results as given by Select query. Is there a way that the view gives the same result as a select query? How can i refresh the view in AThena. Please reply if anyone faced the issue and found a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post DDL statement, i.e. `SHOW CREATE TABLE`,  of the underlying table and how your view looks like, `SHOW CREATE VIEW `. Does the same query on the actual table provide updated results? Where does your new data end up  on S3?

Comment: Views cannot be "refreshed" as they do not contain any data, they just apply the view definition SQL to the underlying tables. If you're not seeing new data after files have been added to S3 I'd suggest checking whether any of the underlying tables are partitioned and, if so, whether the partitions need to be updated e.g. by using `MSCK REPAIR TABLE mydatabase.mytable`

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I have a view in Athena that basically merges 2 tables.
The issue that I'm facing is that if one of the main tables changes (has an extra column) I get the following error: `View 'example_view' is stale or in invalid state: stored view column count (405) does not match column count derived from the view query analysis (406)`

Answer (score 1):

A view could have filters or where clauses that stop the full result set from coming. Assuming view was based on a query like `create view some_vw as select * from table` then all records should come through.